# PayPal REST API Namespace

Tags: php

I followed a tutorial using REST API and code from PayPal's site, and everything works well. There is one thing that needs to be changed and that is the Namespace, which at this time is "Sample." The first line of code on the PHP processing page is:

```
namespace Sample;
```

which just can't be right. I've searched all over in my account and within the documentation, but haven't found this yet. Isn't the PayPal namespace tied to my account in some manner? Doesn't this point to a file path on PayPal's side? Is there a widget that produces this name?

Comment: A namespace is just a PHP construct. It is in no way tied to your PayPal account. It’s just an example. It’s not an _actual_ namespace. You’re meant to use whatever namespace you use in your PHP app; not just literally copy-and-paste `namespace Sample;` into your files.

Comment: Thank you Martin, that's good to know, it will make things easy. Not knowing what PayPal has in their code, I just can't assume anything.